# Kafka Connect - Connect Filters Exclude record when value is null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to add a filter using [connect transforms - filter confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html#filter-confluent) and its not working. The record is passing through another transforms. Here is the code:

```
  "transforms": "unwrap, filterEvent, anotherTransformations",

  "transforms.filterEvent.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
  "transforms.filterEvent.filter.type": "exclude",
  "transforms.filterEvent.filter.condition": "$[?(@.field == null)]",
  "transforms.filterEvent.filter.missing.or.null.behavior": "exclude",
  ...
```

When I change the field value and put another condition like (just for test):
`"transforms.filterEvent.filter.condition": "$[?(@.id == 3)]"`

It works. The filter remove the record that condition returns true.

I'm trying to add a filter using [connect transforms - filter confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html#filter-confluent) and its not working. The record is passing through another transforms. Here is the code:

```
  "transforms": "unwrap, filterEvent, anotherTransformations",

  "transforms.filterEvent.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
  "transforms.filterEvent.filter.type": "exclude",
  "transforms.filterEvent.filter.condition": "$[?(@.field == null)]",
  "transforms.filterEvent.filter.missing.or.null.behavior": "exclude",
  ...
```

When I change the field value and put another condition like (just for test):
`"transforms.filterEvent.filter.condition": "$[?(@.id == 3)]"`

It works. The filter remove the record that condition returns true.